# Why Active MQ Consumer is not recieving any message even if it is online?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, apache-nms

1. Consumer Created.
2. Producer created.
3. Msg Sent.
4. Msg Enqueued in the Queue.
5. But Msg not dequeued (even though there is a consumer online for
   that queue).

There is no error logged on the system.
So What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't called connection.start() then your consumer won't receive anything.  If you have and its still not working then we'd need to see some code in order to help figure it out.

Comment: During this issue, I had used SimpleMessageListenerContainer option, Now i moved to session.CreateConsumer option,There i could recieve msg for normal queue.But in case of temp queue,even the consumer too is not created.I posted it on the new thread here:- http://stackoverflow.com/q/10409242/1121207